# Unexpected nodename when connected to shared network

Tags: networking, macos, r, macos-mojave

I have an R script that I have set up to work on both my local computer (for testing) and a remote server. My local computer runs MacOS Mojave.
To set up the correct file paths for my script's inputs, I use `Sys.info()["nodename"]` to identify my computer (the output is normally either `{my computer's name}.local` or `{the server's name}`.
I am currently in a co-working space and the output of `Sys.info()["nodename"]` appears to be the name of somebody else's computer in the same work space.
I have two questions:

1. Does this raise any red flags regarding my computer's security or privacy? All sharing is turned off in my system preferences.
2. How do I get `Sys.info()["nodename"]` to return its regular output so my code runs as expected both when I'm in the office and in this co-working space?

Comment: I don't know R at all, but I'm assuming you have the same as this common issue - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal

Comment: Thanks for the input. This issue is different, because my computer's name (as defined in System Preferences > sharing) and my terminal match and have the expected values. However, reading that answer set me on the path to answering my question, so thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a pointer from Tetsujin, I was able to answer question 2. I went to `System Preferences > Network > Advanced > WINS` and deleted the contents of the `NETBIOS NAME` field. Once my new preferences were applied, `Sys.info()["nodename"]` gave the expected output.
However,I still don't understand why this happened or what implications might be for my computer's security, and would appreciate more explanation.